# Using an existing canvas on another page in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I'm kinda new in WPF and I like to use an existing canvas with a lot of children on another xaml page. I saved it in a global property, and I want to use it like this:

```
this.DataContext = new TimeDesignerViewModel();
this.myCanvas = (this.DataContext as TimeDesignerViewModel).TdCanvas;
```

When I load the page, there is nothing on a canvas, but in code-behind, there are the children. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never have `UIElements` in `ViewModels`. Secondly, you can't have two parents of same control in WPF. So if you have one `Canvas` child of one `window` the same instance of that `Canvas` cannot be child of other `window/UserControl/Page`.
But if you want to have same layout at both places, what you can do it to define your Canvas as Resource in your `Application.Resources`  in `App.xaml` like

```
<Application.Resources>

    <Canvas x:Key="myCanvas"  x:Shared="false">
    </Canvas>
</Application.Resources>
```

Make sure you set x:Shared="false" in order to create new instance on every demand of Resource.

Now wherever you want to have this resource you can directly refer in xaml as `{StaticResource myCanvas}`

or in code you can have it like `Application.Current.Resources["myCanvas"] as Canvas`

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I just only have one other question: when I like to add an element to the canvas like this:(Application.Current.Resources["myCanvas"] as Canvas).Children.Add(newThumb);

the element won't be in the canvas children list. Am I missing something else?

Comment: yes.. you will have to first add the canvas as the children of window or page whatever you are using.. then add children to it

Comment: Oh, what a noob question, thank you, it's working now! I misunderstood something :)